# /var/cache/apt-show-versions/files: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, apt

When I run `sudo apt-get update` this is the result:

```
can't create /var/cache/apt-show-versions/files: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 196.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

How can I solve this?

Output of `ls -ld /var/cache/apt-show-versions`

```
ls: cannot access /var/cache/apt-show-versions: No such file or directory
```

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -ld /var/cache/apt-show-versions`

Comment: @Ravan I already solve the GPG error. thanks. but there are still error

Comment: @A.B. ok sir. ls -ld /var/cache/apt-show-versions

ls: cannot access /var/cache/apt-show-versions: No such file or directory

Comment: @A.B. done editing the question sir.

Comment: I have replaced your title, I hope it's ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reinstall `apt-show-versions`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt-show-versions
```

or start

```
apt-show-versions -i
```

---

*Explanation*

The folder `/var/cache/apt-show-versions` was probably deleted. Why do I think that? That's why:

I have tested this with

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt-show-versions
```

and when I start

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I have this problem

```
can't create /var/cache/apt-show-versions/files: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 199.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i
```

and the command

```
apt-show-versions -i
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: @A.B simple,precise works!+1;=)

Comment: @A.B. Can you explain what `apt-show-versions` is good for? I know I don't have it installed, but without any problem...

Comment: @ByteCommander The package is not necessary. But I suspect that something is to be installed, that assumes that the package is installed and want to create a directory that can not be created without creating `/var/cache/apt-show-versions/` first.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have added a better explanation into my answer.

Comment: @A.B. thanks, I learned new things. Newbee user.